# Problem to show my API JSON data with typescript

Tags: angular, ionic3

I have a problem with my code.

I want to show all my data as ion item but it's showing nothing.

This is my HTML part :

```
<ion-item  *ngFor = "let item of test"class="col1" col-12 style=" border: none; color:black;text-align: center;">
                                {{item.description}}    
</ion-item>
```

And this is my TS part :

```
let item = 0;
for(let i = 0; i < this.test['0']['data'].sidelined['data'].length; i++){
     let item = this.test['0']['data'].sidelined['data'][i];
     this.item = item;
     console.log(this.item.description);
}
```

Console log give me all the informations as i want to show. But HTML don't show anything.

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: don't work with scope

Comment: @BartoszTermena This is Angular not AngularJS so $scope does not exist.

Comment: where did you define and initialize variable `test` ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you want to do there. The code is looking kind of broken.

In your typescript code you are reassigning to `this.item` multiple times - effectively overwriting `this.item` multiple times. I guess you want to print one line in your html for every entry in `this.test['0']['data'].sidelined['data']`.
In this case you will have to assign that to your item:

`this.item = this.test['0']['data'].sidelined['data']`

and in your html:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let entry of item">
    {{entry.description}}    
</ion-item>
```